# How to make a loop with Javascript that runs through every value of an html text field in a form

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm creating a form that has two input text fields for URL values. The purpose of the form is to concatenate the URL value(s) in field 1 (Starting URL) with the URL value(s) in field 2 (Closing URL); each starting URL has a unique corresponding closing URL. If a user has multiple pairs of starting and closing URLs, I would have to make a loop, but I am having trouble doing so. So, say the user has 2 pairs of URLs they wish to concatenate together. The user would enter each URL value into their respective fields with a single space separating each starting and closing URL from one another. Upon clicking the "concatenate" button, each pair of starting and closing URLs is supposed to spit out a unique URL in the hmtl element "results". So, **for example**, say the user has the following two pairs of starting and closing URLs in the form:

Starting URLs: `https://www.google.com/ https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/`

Closing URLs: `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/ https://outlook.live.com/owa/`

Upon clicking the button "concatenate", the goal is to see the following two lines of concatenated URLs under "results":

```
https://www.google.com/&URL=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2Fu%2F0%2F%20

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/&URL=https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.live.com%2Fowa%2F
```

The function "encodeURIComponent" is being used to encode each closing URL that the user enters. Please let me know if you can help or if any clarity is needed. Code work is below.

```js
function concatenate() {
  var a = document.getElementById('url1').value;
  var b = document.getElementById('url2').value;
  var index;
  var res1 = a.split(" ");
  var res2 = b.split(" ");
  for (index = 0; index < a.length; index++)
    text += "<li>" + res1[index] + "&url=" + encodeURIComponent(res2[index]) + "</li>";
}
}
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = text
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <form id="concatenationform" method=post>
    <h2>Tag Concatenation Form</h2>
    <p>Enter Starting URL(s) Below
      <br>
      <input type=text id=url1 name=url_1 size=50>
      <br>
      <p>Enter Closing URL(s) Below
        <br>
        <input type=text id=url2 name=url_2 size=50>
        <br>
        <button onclick="return concatenate()">Concatenate</button>
      </p>
      <br>
      <p id="results"></p>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are splitting on " " (space) the res2 which has gone through encodeURIComponent. Meaning there are no spaces there to split. Use encodeURIComponent on idividual parts AFTER splitting them on " " (space)

Comment: @NawedKhan - I made your suggestion and the code is still breaking. My edits are now posted.

Comment: You have lots of mismatched braces in the `concatenate` function.

Comment: You should change the button to `type="button"`, otherwise it will submit the form.

Comment: What errors are you getting?  That might help debug.  As another commenter mentioned, you are missing an opening curly brace { after the list of `for` conditions.  I noticed you also don't initialize a value for `text`, so on the first iteration you will be trying to add a string to `undefined`, which may break.  Try adding that brace, and initializing `text` to an empty string `var text = '';` before you start the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of issues here as following:
1. Braces don't match.
2. Button is submitting form
3. Text is not defined
4. Looping on a which is a long string and results in iterating on each character

Here is the fixed code based on issues mentioned above:

html (Button type is button so no submission, no return):

```
<form id="concatenationform" method=post>
  <h2>Tag Concatenation Form</h2>
  <p>Enter Starting URL(s) Below
    <br>
    <input type=text id=url1 name=url_1 size=50>
    <br>
    <p>Enter Closing URL(s) Below
      <br>
      <input type=text id=url2 name=url_2 size=50>
      <br>
      <button type="button" onclick="concatenate()">Concatenate</button>
    </p>
    <br>
    <p id="results"></p>
</form>
```

Javascript (fixed braces, declared text and looping through array):

```
function concatenate() {
  var a = document.getElementById('url1').value;
  var b = document.getElementById('url2').value;
  var index;
  var text = '';
  var res1 = a.split(" ");
  var res2 = b.split(" ");
  for (index = 0; index < res1.length; index++) {
    text += "<li>" + res1[index] + "&url=" + encodeURIComponent(res2[index]) + "</li>";
  }

  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = text;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9tuwd70r/)

Comment: My sincere apologies for forgetting to thank you. Your fix was very helpful, and thanks for introducing me to JSFiddle.

Comment: i'm glad it worked for you. Kindly accept the answer so others can benefit from it too.